# How to install npm on Ubuntu 14 under Travis-CI

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, travis-ci

I'm trying to install the `npm` package on Ubuntu 14 running under Travis-CI.

It install fine on my local Ubuntu 14 install, but on Travis, it fails with the error:

```
[127.0.0.1] out: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/npm_1.3.10~dfsg-1_all.deb (--unpack):
[127.0.0.1] out:  trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/npm', which is also in package nodejs 0.12.7-rwky1~trusty
[127.0.0.1] out: Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
[127.0.0.1] out: Errors were encountered while processing:
[127.0.0.1] out:  /var/cache/apt/archives/npm_1.3.10~dfsg-1_all.deb
[127.0.0.1] out: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
[127.0.0.1] out: 
Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 100 while executing!
Requested: apt-get update --fix-missing; DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes npm
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "apt-get update --fix-missing; DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes npm"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by **not** trying to install the `npm` package.

In my case, I was using [trusty ci environment on Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/) and figured that it came [pre-installed with nodejs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/#Node.JS) (and hence, npm - *I think*). So, from my repo's `.travis.yml` file, I simply **removed the line where I attempted to install `npm`** (in my case: `- sudo apt-get install -y npm` in `before_install` section) **and the build passed** with commands like `npm install` and other `npm` usages in the `install` section of the `.travis.yml` file executing successfully.

I hope that helps!